# Purpose of a MUX with data selector tied to GND?

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, multiplexer

I am studying the schematic of a SDR board, and I've noticed that one input (the PPS) passes through a MUX that has the data selector pin tied to GND --- thus effectively always choosing the PPS signal.

[image: Fragment of the schematic I am studying]

What is the purpose of such a configuration? I have hypothesized that it is used to somehow decouple the input, but mine is just a guess, and I've been unable to find a reference to such a technique on the net.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It acts as a non-inverting digital buffer. If there's one or more similar parts on the PCB they may have chosen to use an additional NC7SV157 rather than introduce another part number to the BOM. They're like 7 cents each so it wouldn't be a particularly high-stakes decision (assuming availability doesn't figure into it).

Comment: Actually there is one used, with the same technique, for the PPS out. It is also marked in another place on a block diagram of the board, but I cannot find it :S
Anyways, your answer seems to be very plausible, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

> *What is the purpose of such a configuration?*

It could be as simple as "*that's how the circuit board evolved*".

In other words, the original design requirements suggested that the multiplexer might be needed then, after development of a prototype, it was felt to be not needed and, the simplest solution was to permanently enable the flow of the input signal rather than remove the IC from the circuit board.

There might be other reasons of course but, without a detailed history of the product design development, this will be impossible to say.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no info other than the PDF of the schematic... It could, however, be something legacy from a previous board version...
Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

As some have already pointed out it was the natural evolution of the design.
Other reasons may be that :

1. This MUX is actually being used in other parts of the design and instead of introducing another specific component, the designer chose to use an existing component for buffering the input signal (even though the design would have called for a high speed buffer or similar).
2. Related to the above reason, the alternative component may have had an identical footprint and there was no reason change this so as to keep within the existing library of footprints.
3. The characteristics of the MUX are very well suited to the input signal and this was a choice made based on characteristics etc. Notice the datasheet mentions : "The NC7SV157 is uniquely designed for optimized power and speed".
4. Pure and simply, supply issues prevented that a more suitable part was chosen, and instead a suitable compromise was made so as to get the circuit build tested and manufactured due to real-life project time constraints. So it may have been the only part available for the job and it was chosen as it fitted the requirements etc.

Answer (score 1):

The part likely has multiple purposes why specificaly it is selected. It may even depend on the properties of the signal it is receiving to be compatible with it. There may be multiple parts that could have been used, or it was simply used because previous design had two inputs maybe.

The part is a high impedance receiver which supports standard TTL voltage levels on input. A part with CMOS inputs may not work depending on signal properties, if it is driven by standard TTL outputs.

The part also does not load the signal and won't damage when the 3.3V supply is turned off. Other similar parts may not have that property.

The part output has very strong driver to send the signal around the circuit and drive multiple inputs if necessary. The delay through the chip is quite low.

It also does not invert the signal. It is used as non-inverting buffer for the signal input stage, as it has desirable properties for what it needs to do with the signal.